# What does write operations (every 4MB, per 10000) mean?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/storage/data-lake/

Under transaction pricing there is Write operations (every 4MB, per 10000).

What is 10000? And what does every 4MB per 10000 mean?

Answer (score 1):

**Transactions** are incurred any time you read and write data operations to the service.

Each transaction can consist of maximum size of **4MB data**.

So let us assume that you are writing a 8MB data to service - then there will be counted as 2 transactions. Similarly, if one read operation gets 10MB of data. It will be considered as 3 transactions (4+4+2)

So, let us assume that you are writing only data of 256 KB - it will still be considered as a single transaction. (Anything up to 4MB will be considered as 1 transaction.)

Coming back to your question :

[image]

As per the above logic, Write operations for **10000** transactions with **4MB** as Max data size for each transaction would be **Rs. 4.296** for the hot and **Rs.8.592** for cold.

Comment: For storage that will be having 1 write of 15GB per day (data cleared off at end of day) and 10 reads of 10GB per day; which is appropriate mode between hot and cold.

Comment: I think cool tier would be appropriate because it is stored < 30 days and frequency of read and write is very less. Hot is preferred only when there is very active use or expected to be accessed (read from and written to) frequently

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding this explanation but it seems wrong:

If it's saying that the charge is for 10,000 transactions with up to 4MB per transaction (i.e. 40GB across 10k transactions) then this is wrong.
The charges are *per* transaction up to a max of 4MB per transaction e.g. a single read/write of 10MB data incurs 3 transaction charges.

The ADLS Storage team at Microsoft maintain an FAQ that explains this better although it's still not entirely clear: (https://azure.github.io/Storage/docs/analytics/azure-storage-data-lake-gen2-billing-faq/).

The FAQ seems to suggest that reading/writing data from/to a file is based on the "per 4MB approach" whilst metadata operations (Copy File, Rename, Set Properties, etc) are charged on a per 10k operations basis.

So effectively data read/writes are charged per transaction up to 4MB (single transactions >4MB are charged as multiple 4MB transactions), whilst metadata operations are charged on a per 10,000 operations basis.

How you're ever supposed to work out how much this is going to cost upfront is beyond me...